# Should a language model like GPT-3 be directly used to perform classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, language-models, bayes-optimal-classifier

The [OpenAI API enables classification by sampling from GPT-3 given a prompt](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/completion/classification). Is estimating posterior probabilities a more statistically sound approach? Below is a specification of what "estimating posterior probabilities" could mean here. I'd like feedback on how sensible it is (see the question at the bottom).

## Definitions

- $\mathcal{X}$ is the set of all possible sequences of tokens. $x \in \mathcal{X}$ is a sequence of tokens. For example, a movie review could be $x = (\text{A}, \text{ thrill}, \text{ ride}, \text{ for}, \text{ the}, \text{ ages}, \text{!}, \text{ --}, \text{Peter}, \text{ K}, \text{ Rosenthal})$.
- $\Pr_{\theta}$ is a language model, i.e., a probability distribution over $\mathcal{X}$ parametrized by $\theta$.
- $Y$ is a random variable for the class an observation belongs to, where the set of classes is $\mathcal{Y}$. Let's allow $\mathcal{Y} \subset \mathcal{X}$. So if I'm classifying movie reviews, $\mathcal{Y} = \{ \text{Just another superhero movie}, \text{Generic hype} \}$ represents a classification task.
- The function $\text{prompt}: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ takes a sequence of tokens (which must include $x$, and optionally $\mathcal{Y}$) and returns a new sequence of tokens. A prompt asks a language model to perform the task.

  - See [this set of documentation](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/completion/classification) for more examples and detail. (You need to pay to hit OpenAI API endpoints.)

## Proposed method

GPT-3's estimates, $\Pr_\theta(x_i \: | \: x_{1:i-1})$, are great. So simply selecting the completion from $\mathcal{Y}$ with the highest posterior probability should be more direct than sampling. For example, we'd query the language model for its probability of this prompt and completion:

```
This movie review
"""
A thrill ride for the ages! --Peter K Rosenthal
"""
is best categorized as {completion}.
```

where `{completion}` is replaced w/ `"Just another superhero movie"`, and then replaced w/ `"Generic hype"`.

I'll start w/ a false start to formalizing the meaning of posterior probability here, and then adjust it. **I'm dubious about the adjustment though, so I'd like feedback.**

First some new definitions: let $c \in \mathcal{Y}$ be a completion containing $n$ tokens, and $p = \text{prompt}(x)$ be the prompt. In the example above, the prompt is the full sequence of tokens up until  `{completion}`.

False start: it's tempting to simply do $\arg\max_{c \in \mathcal{Y}} \Pr_\theta(c \: | \: p)$. This is wrong b/c longer completions trivially result in lower probabilities. It also asks the language model to do too much work, as it doesn't incorporate the prior $\Pr(y)$ from your specific distribution. It implicitly comes from GPT-3's training distribution as $\Pr_\theta(c)$. (But [this prior can be manually set](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-logit_bias) for single-token completions.)

Now for the adjustments: start w/ framing the classifier as

$$
\begin{equation}
\arg\max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \Pr(y \: | \: p, c) = \arg\max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \text{Pr}_\theta(p, c \: | \: y) \Pr(y).
\end{equation}
$$

This reframing fixes the issue with the prior. (**Edit**: it seems to not be enough when there's a uniform prior. See the edit in the [updated answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/606323/337906).) To fix the completion length issue, let's replace $\Pr_\theta(p, c \: | \: y)$ with an average per completion token. To construct that, we'll first express $\Pr_\theta(p, c \: | \: y)$ as

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Pr}_\theta(p, c \: | \: y) &= \text{Pr}_\theta(p \: | \: y) \text{Pr}_\theta(c \: | \: p, y) && \text{probability chain rule} \\
&= \text{Pr}_\theta(p) \text{Pr}_\theta(c \: | \: p, y) && P=p \perp Y=y \\
&= \text{Pr}_\theta(p) \prod_{i=1}^{n} \text{Pr}_\theta(c_i \: | \: p, y, c_{1:i-1}) && \text{probability chain rule} \\
&= \text{Pr}_\theta(p) \exp \Bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log\text{Pr}_\theta(c_i \: | \: p, y, c_{1:i-1}) \Bigg\}.
\end{align}
$$

Note that we can ignore $\Pr_\theta(p)$ as it doesn't depend on $y$. The completion does depend on the class b/c it's set to the class.

Define the average likelihood (i.e., the average inverse perplexity<sup>1,2</sup>) as

$$
\begin{equation*}
\bar{\text{Pr}}_\theta(c \: | \: p, y) =  \exp \Bigg\{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log\text{Pr}_\theta(c_i \: | \: p, y, c_{1:i-1}) \Bigg\}.
\end{equation*}
$$

Finally, estimate the posterior probability of a class, AKA the **C**ompletion **A**fter **P**rompt **Pr**obability, as

$$
\begin{equation*}
\text{CAPPr}(y \: | \: p, c) = \bar{\text{Pr}}_\theta(c \: | \: p, y) \Pr(y) / Z
\end{equation*}
$$

where $Z$ is the normalizer.

#### Example

Let's perform the estimation for the $x$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ movie review example. $p = \text{prompt}(x)$ is this sequence of tokens:

```
This movie review
"""
A thrill ride for the ages! --Peter K Rosenthal
"""
is best categorized as
```

Example computation for the second class:

$$
\begin{equation*}
\bar{\text{Pr}}_\theta(c \: | \: p, \text{Generic hype}) = \exp \Bigg\{ \frac{1}{2} \Big[ \log \text{Pr}_\theta(\text{Generic} \: | \: p) + \log \text{Pr}_\theta(\text{hype} \: | \: p, \text{Generic}) \Big] \Bigg\}.
\end{equation*}
$$

Say I magically know the class distribution for my data:

$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{Just another superhero movie}) = 1/3 \\
\Pr(\text{Generic hype}) = 2/3.
\end{align*}
$$

Then the normalizer is

$$
\begin{equation*}
Z = \frac{1}{3} \bar{\text{Pr}}_\theta(c \: | \: p, \text{Just another superhero movie}) + \frac{2}{3} \bar{\text{Pr}}_\theta(c \: | \: p, \text{Generic hype}).
\end{equation*}
$$

Finally, the posterior probability estimates are

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{CAPPr}(\text{Just another superhero movie} \: | \: p, c) &= \frac{1}{3} \bar{\text{Pr}}_\theta(c \: | \: p, \text{Just another superhero movie}) / Z \\
\text{CAPPr}(\text{Generic hype} \: | \: p, c) &= \frac{2}{3} \bar{\text{Pr}}_\theta(c \: | \: p, \text{Generic hype}) / Z.
\end{align*}
$$

## Question

Did it make sense to reframe the classifier from

$$
\arg\max_{c \in \mathcal{Y}} \text{Pr}_\theta(c \: | \: p) \\
\text{to} \\
\arg\max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \text{CAPPr}( y \: | \: c, p) ?
$$

## References

1. [Wikipedia page on perplexity per word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity#Perplexity_per_word)
2. [huggingface's perplexity documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perplexity)

Comment: One potential pitfall of the proposed method is that posterior probabilities of classes whose corresponding completions are already likely according to the LM may be inflated. For example, a class "great movie" will likely have higher probabilities than a class "artistic film". This bias may be undesirable for many text classification tasks. And idk if conditioning on the prompt is enough to overcome it.

But I don't see how this is a disadvantage when compared to sampling from the LM, which is the baseline. I'll run an experiment on a hard text classification problem and provide an update.

Comment: Another issue is that the number of inference computations is directly proportional to the number of classes. If $x$ contains enough tokens, then for OpenAI API clients, this means higher costs.

Comment: The issue w/ computation being proportional to the number of classes was addressed by caching each attention block's keys and values. See [this notebook](https://github.com/kddubey/callm/blob/main/demos/computational_analysis.ipynb) for a comparison b/t estimation and sampling.

Comment: So, I don't have the NLP background to fully answer this, but what you're describing is an instance of "in-context learning," in which you can approximate functions (i.e. tokens -> other tokens) simply via prompting. Google BIG-BENCH has a few examples of such tasks. I'm not sure if this will answer your question fully, but https://ai.stanford.edu/blog/understanding-incontext/ seems to be an interesting starting point to explore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I evaluated the proposed method on the [Choice of Plausible Alternatives (COPA) task](https://people.ict.usc.edu/%7Egordon/copa.html). I picked this task from the [SuperGLUE](https://super.gluebenchmark.com/tasks) NLP benchmark b/c each $c \in \mathcal{Y}$ is always a few tokens long.

See the [evaluation notebook here](https://github.com/kddubey/cappr/blob/main/demos/openai/superglue/copa.ipynb).

I still need to empirically evaluate calibration, and evaluate on more classification tasks. But a partial, empirical answer to the question in the title and the "Did it make sense..." question is: yes. Zero-shot accuracy on COPA train + validation is 0.92-0.95 depending on the prompt, which is comparable to text generation + post-processing. (Majority class gives 0.5 accuracy.)

**Edit**: after some more experimentation, it seems like the issue with the prior coming from $\Pr_\theta(c)$ is not fully resolved. In other words, the average likelihood of completions which are really common—regardless of the prompt—is often too high. I hypothesized that this would be an issue in [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601159/should-a-language-model-like-gpt-3-be-directly-used-to-perform-classification#comment1122997_601159).

The solution I'm rolling with for now is to do something along the lines of replacing the marginal class probability in Bayes' rule. (I did a similar thing with some success in [this separate work](https://github.com/kddubey/stackexchange/blob/main/precision_drop.ipynb). See the section **A simple fix**.)

We can introduce a "discount" hyperparameter which controls how much $\Pr_\theta(c)$ counts toward the average likelihood. Modify

$$
\begin{equation*}
\text{Pr}_\theta(c \: | \: p) \propto \text{Pr}_\theta(p \: | \: c) \text{Pr}_\theta(c)
\end{equation*}
$$

to

$$
\begin{equation*}
\log\text{Pr}_\theta(p \: | \: c) \text{Pr}_\theta(c)^\gamma = \log\text{Pr}_\theta(p \: | \: c) + \gamma\log\text{Pr}_\theta(c).
\end{equation*}
$$

Skipping some steps (and ignoring the unease with the ill-defined $\text{Pr}_\theta(p \: | \: c)$ term), this fudged expression is incorporated into the average likelihood as:

$$
\begin{equation*}
\bar{\text{Pr}}_\theta(c \: | \: p, y) =  \exp \Bigg\{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log\text{Pr}_\theta(c_i \: | \: p, y, c_{1:i-1}) + \gamma \log\text{Pr}_{\theta}(c_i \: | \: y, c_{1:i-1}) \Bigg\}.
\end{equation*}
$$

Setting $\gamma = 0$ obviously applies no discount. Setting $0 < \gamma < 1$ applies some discount. Setting $\gamma = 1$ is equivalent to dropping $\Pr_\theta(c)$, which should directly counteract the issue. Increasing $\gamma > 1$ further penalizes completions with higher priors, which doesn't seem sensible.